# count number of streams multiplexed in http2

Tags: wireshark, http2, pcap, multiplexing

I'm having 5 connections from client to server using http2(tcp.

I set the maxconcurrent streams to 3 in http2 field

How can I find number of streams in a connection in http2 from pcap file in Wireshark

Answer (score 0):

The `max_concurrent_stream` options is negotiated by client and server by exchanging SETTINGS frames, as specified in [RFC 7540](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540).

For more details see [this section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-6.5.2).

Wireshark can dissect HTTP/2 traffic, so you need to find the SETTINGS frames that are exchanged, typically just after the connection is established, and look in the SETTINGS frames for the key `0x03` that correspond to `SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS` and its corresponding value.